# Why is the code detecting the outer most )

Tags: python

The problem here asks me to reverse any string inside (). Let's say if my the string is "foo(bar(baz))blim", then the returned result would be "foobazrabblim" . Someone helped me with the coding process, however, I still don't understand why the code is detecting the outer ) first.

```
def reverseInParentheses(inputString):
    n=len(inputString)
    for i in range(n):
        if inputString[i] == "(":
            start=i          
        if inputString[i] == ")":
            end=i          
            return reverseInParentheses(inputString[:start]+
inputString[start+1:end][::-1]+inputString[end+1:n])
        return inputString
```

For what I understand, let's say we have "foo(bar(baz))blim". So python detect start=3, end=11. then we call function reverseinparetheses, we will have "foozab(rab)blim". Going through the function again, there is the new start=6, end=10. In the end, we have "foozabbarblim" which is not "foobazrabblim" that we are expecting. I am wondering how is the program detecting the outer ")" first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not detecting the outermost parentheses. It's finding the innermost pair, reversing the inside, and then repeating until there are no more parentheses.

```
if inputString[i] == ")":
    ....
```

This block fires when you've hit the first ')', and at that stage `start` will be the '(' that opens the first ')'. This is the innermost pair.

Then you have:

```
return reverseInParentheses(inputString[:start]+inputString[start+1:end][::-1]+inputString[end+1:n])
```

This reverses the content from start to end (the innermost pair) and then calls the function, cutting off the rest of the for loop.

If you actually print `inputString` at each step you get:

```
foo(bar(baz))blim
foo(barzab)blim
foobazrabblim
```

Innermost parentheses are getting reversed.

Comment: Therefore, the if statement works like so: we found the first "(", but there is another one after it, so it detects start=7 in the first round. But why does the code run when we hit the first ")"?

Comment: See: `if inputString[i] == ")":` this fires once you hit the first ")", and look at what happens next: `return reverseInParentheses(inputString[:start]+inputString[start+1:end][::-1]+inputString[end+1:n])` this is reversing the innermost pair and returning immediately, cutting off the rest of the for loop.

Comment: Let me know if this is correct now: With the first round, python detected twice for the first if: first time start=3, second time start=7, then with the second if, since we are returning reverseInParetheses right after making end=11, that's why we returned the inner most ()?

Comment: Yep, and then you're starting the cycle over again but with the innermost reversed.